# Change the question title if the real issue is different

Tags: discussion, edits, title

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316905/c-program-stopped-working-after-use-scanf), for example. The question title is *"C program stopped working after use scanf"*, but the real issue has nothing to do with `scanf`. Instead, the problem was the consequence of a wrong syntax used for `printf`.

Now, after the OP accepting the actual solution, **is it OK to change the question title** to *"Problem with printf [...]"* or a similar one? **Or should the question have been flagged for closure instead?**

Comment: That's a terrible question and title either way.  I would normally suggest an actual title, but I can't think of one for a "help me debug my random program" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the fact that that kind of question should have been immediately closed as off-topic as per:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

The edit itself would have been legit, still not improving the quality of the question. Therefore, **a question like that one shouldn't have been edited at all, and should have been proposed to be closed instead**.

---

Now, talking about the more general problem:

> Should I change the question title if the real issue is different?

I think that you should first **comment** on the question telling to the OP that his title is wrong and should be changed. If no response is given, then **edit the question's title by yourself**, carefully explaining *why* you did it in the edit summary.